# Best way to present a ViewController from many different ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, presentviewcontroller

I have `n` number of different `ViewController's`, so I want to present a `PresentViewController` from any other ViewControllers in `Objective-C`

**How I am doing Currently:**

So currently i am doing like this `import "PresentViewController.h"` in all ViewControllers then calling following code to present it:

```
NSString * storyboardName = @"MainStoryboard"; 
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle: nil];
PresentViewController * vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"IDENTIFIER_OF_YOUR_VIEWCONTROLLER"];
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

But by this way I have to import `"PresentViewController.h"` file into all other `ViewControllers` which seems very irritating job.

**What I am looking for:**

Is there any other way to present PresentViewController from a particular place and it can be presented whenever it needed from any ViewControllers?

Answer (score 0):

If that is really all the code you've got, you are not *doing* anything with PresentViewController unique to it, so just don't mention it by name in your code:

```
UIViewController * vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"IDENTIFIER_OF_YOUR_VIEWCONTROLLER"];
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

If you don't mention it in your code, you don't need to import it.

But obviously if you *do* something with PresentViewController, like call a method of it, then things are more complicated. You could cast to `id`, in which case you can call *any* method, provided the compiler knows about it (also known as an informal protocol). But in general it would be better just to bite the bullet and do the import.

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn’t that you have to import that header all over the place, but rather that:

- you’re repeating that code all over the place;
- you’re exposing internal implementation details about `PresentViewController` (such as its storyboard name and storyboard identifier) to other classes; and
- if you ever want to change this to include some additional parameter, you’re going to have to manually hunt through your code for where changes are necessary rather than just changing some public interface that the compiler will then be able to warn you of issues.

Personally, I’d define an extension to `UIViewController`:

```
// UIViewController+Foo.h

@interface UIViewController(Foo)

- (void)presentFoo;
- (void)presentFooWithCompletion:(void (^)(void))completion;

@end
```

And

```
// UIViewController+Foo.m

@implementation UIViewController(Foo)

- (void)presentFoo {
    [self presentFooWithCompletion:nil];
}

- (void)presentFooWithCompletion:(void (^)(void))completion {
    NSString *storyboardName = @"MainStoryboard";
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle: nil];
    UIViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"IDENTIFIER_OF_YOUR_VIEWCONTROLLER"];
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:completion];
}

@end
```

Then any view controller that needs to present this scene can have

```
#import “UIViewController+Foo.h”
```

And

```
[self presentFoo];
```

Or if you don’t want it as an extension to `UIViewController`, you could define these as class methods (using the `+` instead of `-`) of your `PresentViewController`. But the idea is the same: Define some simple interface that all your view controllers can call without getting lost in the implementation details of `PresentViewController`.

Now, obviously, I have no idea what this view controller does, so I used `Foo` as a placeholder. You’d obviously replace that with whatever the functional purpose of this view controller is. E.g. if it was to present a “network error” message, then I’d call the methods and filenames with `presentNetworkError`, `UIViewController+NetworkError.h`, etc. But hopefully this illustrates the idea.